# Why must I source .bashrc every time I open terminal for aliases to work?

Tags: bash, shell

Git was working fine. I have created an alias in Git but the issue is when I tried to reopen the terminal, then I need to run `. ~/.bashrc` every time in the terminal.

What is the best way I don't need to provide source every time when I reopen the terminal?

**What I did?** 
I am trying to add `source` of the `.bashrc` file in this file but it is a read-only file. I am not able to add the `source` of the `.bashrc` file in this profile.

```
open /etc/profile
```

Added the permission to write in the profile as well, still not able to link the source file.

```
sudo chmod u+w /etc/profile
```

**Profile:**

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
   eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
   [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Aren’t you running another shell (Zsh, Fish, Dash, …) instead of Bash?

Comment: No i am not running any another shell

Comment: A) dont you make /etc/profile general writeable. It is owned by root, and your local user(s) shouldnt have write access to it B) how are you opening a terminal?

Comment: Which OS are you using, which terminal and how do you start it.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Seirra OS Mac

Comment: i am using . ~/.bashrc to start the alias

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like your terminal emulator is launching `bash` as a login shell.

If that's the case, it will read `/etc/profile` for configuration as well as **1 of the following files**, if they exist (listed in order of importance) :

- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.bash_login
- ~/.profile

It will thus ignore your `.bashrc` file. A correct fix for your situation would be to either configure your terminal emulator to run bash interactively and non-login, or add the following line to your `~/.bash_profile` :

`[ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && . "$HOME/.bashrc"`

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) is a link to the documentation about which files are loaded depending of the type of shell you are running

Comment: I would add, that with the stock Debian install, a new user's home directory is prepopulated with `~/.bash_profile` which sources `~/.bashrc`, so yes, the fix proposed by Aserre is indeed what it's supposed to work.

Comment: What i did i just created bash_profile in the home directory i tried to find earlier but it is not there in my home root folder so i have created a file and followed your answer then it is working for me ..

Answer (score 13):

As per @Aserre's answer i have followed this step to solve this issue

A typical install of OS won't create a .bash_profile for you. When you want to run functions from your command line, this is a must-have.

1. Start up Terminal
2. Type `cd ~/` to go to your home folder
3. Type `touch .bash_profile` to create your new file.
4. Edit .bash_profile with your favorite editor (or you can just type `open -e .bash_profile` to open it in TextEdit.
5. `[ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"` Save it and close it

Restart the terminal, It should work

Answer (score 1):

You should write this line `source .profile` inside your `.zshrc` file. This is because default shell is *zsh*. If u don't want to do this solution than u can go for changing the default shell by typing the following command `chsh -s /bin/bash` then restart your machine or virtual machine. Then no need for source. I hope this will help :) TAKE CARE

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux and you want variables set, to persist.
Follow the below steps.

1. Be the root user -> **sudo su**
2. go to etc folder -> **cd /etc**
3. open the file bashrc with the editor of your choice -> **vi bashrc**
4. set the variable with export command like here I am setting JAVA_HOME ->

```
export JAVA_HOME=pathHere
```

5. Load the bashrc file with command ->

```
. bashrc
```

remember to put the dot/period before bashrc.
now JAVA_HOME should be set permanently.
Thanks...