# Path in .bash_profile give error: "-bash: flutter: command not found"

Tags: android, bash, macos, flutter

I am following Flutter official documentation for adding flutter Path in **.bash_profile** in order to run commands on terminal but it give me error
`-bash: flutter: command not found`

Is there any quick way to add Flutter support in android studio for was Android Developers. I am trying to find the easy way to add Flutter support on running Android environment.

My .bash_profile contains the following line:
`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Developer/flutter/bin"`

I have tried all my possible answers but no luck.
P.S I'm using bash not zsh any other.

Comment: Could you post the relevant `.bash_profile` code sample ? Do the other commands in your `.bash_profile` execute correctly ?

Comment: [Are you sure your terminal is executed as a login shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876792/why-must-i-source-bashrc-every-time-i-open-terminal-for-aliases-to-work/51877640#51877640) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. I assume that you've downloaded the flutter SDK from official docs as I did and tried so many solutions.

I resolved this issue with the following steps:

1. download the Android Studio
2. Open Android studio's preferences -> Plugins -> download flutter plugin
3. File -> New -> Create New Flutter project
4. In the next dialogue under the "Flutter SDK path" you can see **install SDK...** option (install the SDK from there at your desired location)
5. Once SDK is installed then update your .bash_profile with the newly downloaded SDK.

Your .bash_profile should look something like this:

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Developer/flutter/bin"`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Umair using this method automatically set variable paths and other stuff to running the project.