# Azure DevOps Pipeline: bash task doesn't pick up .bashrc or /etc/profiles from Ubuntu based EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, azure-pipelines, ubuntu-18.04

We are using Azure DevOps Pipelines to orchestrate bash scripts on EC2 instances in AWS, running Ubuntu 18.04.

Within the pipelines, we mostly have bash tasks with inline scripts.

We'd like the bash tasks to pick up environment variables from both `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/profiles`, so we made sure to uncheck the advanced options *"Don't load the profile startup/initialization files"* and *"Don't read the ~/.bashrc initialization file"*.

Nevertheless, neither init file seems to be read.

See our example bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -i

echo "HTTP_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}"
source /etc/profile
echo "HTTP_PROXY=${HTTP_PROXY}"

echo "SOMEVAR=${SOMEVAR}"
source ~/.bashrc
echo "SOMEVAR=${SOMEVAR}"
```

... will ouput:

```
HTTP_PROXY=
HTTP_PROXY=<some-proxy-host>:<some-port>
SOMEVAR=
SOMEVAR=
```

We only get our proxy variables *after* sourcing `/etc/profiles` explicitly.

Also, sourcing `~/.bashrc` does not work as expected; possibly this is because the script is not run in interactive bash mode.
Looking into `~/.bashrc` we see that interactive mode is needed, otherwise it will quit immediately:

```sh
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Why does `/etc/profiles` not get sourced automatically?
How can we make sure to have the bash tasks run in interactive mode?

Comment: Do you have the same behaviour with `~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: Yes, also ```~/.bashrc``` does not get loaded.  I wonder if this has to do with bash not being run in interactive mode...?

Comment: do you have the exact same behaviour with `~/.bashrc` ? i.e. nothing on the first echo, and a value once you manually source `~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: @Aserre I updated my post and gave some more details, also regarding the ```~/.bashrc``` issue

Comment: Could you type `cat ~/.bashrc` in your script ? My guess : 1) bash is launched as a non-login shell, so [the profile files are not read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51877640/2057091) 2) If `cat ~/.bashrc` is blank or does not contains your config, it means the user who owns the `bashrc` file you configured is not the same as the one running the script.

Comment: Though it's 2 and half years later, I met the same issue and found in pipeline logs that AWS run the CI script with the following command: `/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /.../<script_id>.sh`, as you see, no profile and no rc.